# Error while importing gensim library value error

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

while i am importing the library gensim
`import gensim`

it throws this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14076/1427573704.py in <module>
----> 1 import gensim

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py in <module>
      9 import logging
     10 
---> 11 from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
     12 
     13 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # bring corpus classes directly into package namespace, to save some typing
----> 6 from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
      7 
      8 from .mmcorpus import MmCorpus  # noqa:F401

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\indexedcorpus.py in <module>
     12 import numpy
     13 
---> 14 from gensim import interfaces, utils
     15 
     16 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gensim\interfaces.py in <module>
     17 import logging
     18 
---> 19 from gensim import utils, matutils
     20 
     21 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py in <module>
   1028 try:
   1029     # try to load fast, cythonized code if possible
-> 1030     from gensim._matutils import logsumexp, mean_absolute_difference, dirichlet_expectation
   1031 
   1032 except ImportError:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gensim\_matutils.pyx in init gensim._matutils()

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject`
```

What is the solution of this error?

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstall gensim, use a venv to troubleshot, it may come from different versionning of other librairies

Answer (score 0):

This likely means you've installed mismatched versions of libraries that closely depend on each other, like Gensim and Numpy.

In such cases, as ~zanga suggests, starting from a fresh Python environment with no optional libraries yet installed is likely to help. As you install just what you need, you'll get the latest/compatible libraries.

In general it is best to use independent Python virtual environments for your own separate coding project, as supported by the Python 3 `venv` functionality, or also well-implemented by the `conda` package/environment management too.

Then, you *don't* change the shared system Python environment with mixed mismatches of libraries that can risk:

- library choices you made in an earlier project negatively impacting later projects
- new libraries in later project inadvertently *breaking* earlier projects, which have their preferred versions changed out-from-under-them
- being unsure what libraries/versions are needed for a project when you move it elsewhere or share it with others (because sufficient libraries just happened to already be there without proper explicit declaration)